# Can I buy a Locking Thru Axle for extra security?

Tags: lock, security, through-axle

I've seen security skewers for quick release wheels such as [pitlock](https://www.pitlock.de) or [pinhead](https://pinheadlocks.com/) which provide some level of additional security for wheels without carrying bulky locks for wheels (Still wise to use a lock on your frame).

With new bike technology and expensive lightweight hub/wheel builds, it seems like it's difficult to find solutions to secure these wheels a bit better than quick release thru axles. Thru axles are commonplace on mountain bikes and becoming more common on road/cross/adventure bikes.

Though I have seen options for bolt on thru axles, which at least require an Allen key, I have not really seen the same variety of security skewers that use a specialized tool or key to open. What are my options for skewer based security on thru axle bikes?

(May need to consider regular mtb hub spacing, boost, fat bike axle sizes)

Answer (score 3):

Looks like Pinhead and others are selling through-axle kits. Do a web search on "anti-theft through axle."